# When do ﬂoors and ceilings matter while solving recurrences?

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence, asymptotic-complexity

I came across places where floors and ceilings are neglected while solving recurrences.

Example from [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) *(chapter 4, pg.83)* where floor is neglected:

[image]

[Here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Enam1/TA/HWSols/hw2sol.pdf) (*pg.2, exercise 4.1–1*) is an example where ceiling is ignored:
*(EDIT: I gather from public opinion that this is somewhat fishy.)*

[image]

In fact in [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) (*pg.88*) its mentioned that:

**"Floors and ceilings USUALLY do not matter when solving recurrences"**

My questions:

1. Here does "usually" means ALL cases ? If yes, i can just forget them all the time.
2. If not, then **when do floors and ceilings really count while solving recurrences** ?

*Note: This ain't a homework problem. I thought about it while I was refreshing my DS and algo concepts.*

Comment: In your examples, it's not being neglected.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: yes..thats what i have seen so far that its neglected. Even CLRS mentions "its USUALLY neglected". I want to know when do floor and ceiling really bother ? or can i just keep on neglecting them ALL the time ?

Comment: … also, this is a math question, not programming. At a glance, the reason the floor/ceilings are being eliminated by inequality is that asymptotic behaviors are being examined; the recurrence isn't being solved at all.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : I have seen questions on recurrences, big Oh etc.. algorithmn stuff being posted on SO which were not directly related to programming. If this ain't the right place to post my question, can you suggest a good place ?

Comment: @TejasP http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The floor and ceiling functions satisfy the following inequalities for all *x*:

- *x*−1 < ⌊*x*⌋ ≤ *x*
- *x* ≤ ⌈*x*⌉ < *x*+1

Thus, in the first example, we have ⌊*n* / 2⌋ ≤ *n* / 2.  Also, since the logarithm is a monotone increasing function, we know that lg ⌊*n* / 2⌋ ≤ lg(*n* / 2).  Putting these together, we get the first inequality 2(*c* ⌊*n* / 2⌋ lg ⌊*n* / 2⌋) + *n* ≤ *cn* lg(*n* / 2) + *n*.

The second example actually contains an error: *c* lg ⌈*n* / 2⌉ + 1 is never less than but can be equal to *c* lg(*n* / 2) + 1.  However, it *is* true that *c* lg ⌈*n* / 2⌉ + 1 ≤ *c* lg(*n* / 2 + 1) + 1, which we can then bound from above by, say, *c* lg(*n* / 2) + 2 (assuming that *n* ≥ 2) and thus derive the desired conclusion that *T*(*n*) ∈ *O*(lg *n*).

In fact, the second example contains other errors too: even with the assumptions stated in the following paragraph (which you did not quote), the last = sign should be ≤.

(Ps. Phew, this was a real pain to type without LaTeX.  That, if nothing else, is why questions like these are better asked on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).)

Comment: @ilmariKaronen : thnkx for the explanation. So can i say that ceilings can never be ignored while using susbtitution method ?

Comment: @TejasP: For floors, f(⌊x⌋) ≤ f(x) for any monotone increasing function f.  This does not hold for ceilings, but we can always use f(⌈x⌉) ≤ f(x+1) instead.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen 8 years is a long time but nonetheless can you explain as to how f(⌈x⌉) ≤ f(x+1) holds true I mean f(⌈x⌉) <  f(x+1)  holds for sure but how'd you say ≤ holds true

Comment: @lava_07: f(x) = 42 is a monotone increasing function (although not _strictly_ increasing). f(⌈x⌉) < f(x+1) holds if f is strictly increasing, but f(⌈x⌉) = f(x+1) is also possible if f happens to be constant within the interval from ⌈x⌉ to x+1.

Comment: On the same note isn't log strictly increasing? like if I consider the interval between ⌈x⌉ to x+1 will log ever be a constant? if I am not mistaken log is also a one to one function that probably rules out constant intervals? (correct me if I am wrong not really a maths guy! )

Comment: @lava_07: Yes, the logarithm function is strictly increasing, at least as defined mathematically. Off the top of my head, I'm not 100% sure whether that's still guaranteed to hold even after accounting for floating-point inaccuracy, but I suspect it isn't. (Then again, with floating point, you can't really even guarantee that x+1 ≥ x.)

Comment: So for upper bounding (c lg ⌈n / 2⌉ + 1)  is (c lg(n / 2 + 1) + 1) still valid ? as in < definitely holds true but mathematically speaking for the above recurrence relation is upper bounding it with <= valid? (I do not know if this makes sense!)

Comment: @lava_07: Well, x < y implies x ≤ y, so, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Both of your examples are amenable to analysis by the Master Theorem. The [Akra–Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_method) generalizes the Master Theorem and gives a sufficient condition for when small perturbations can be ignored (the perturbation h(x) is O(x/log<sup>2</sup> x)). For integer-indexed recurrences analyzable by Akra–Bazzi, you can ignore the floor and ceiling *always*, since their perturbations are at most 1.

Every recurrence not covered by Akra–Bazzi is quite exotic in the context of algorithms and data structures.

Comment: thnkx for pointing Akra–Bazzi theorem.i didnt knew it before....can i say the same for susbtitution method (ie. floor & ceilings always be ignored) ?

Comment: If your guess for T increases monotonically and you're happy with an upper bound, then you can always ignore floor. To deal with ceiling formally, usually one has to analyze T(ceil(...)) as T(...) + ... where the second ... is a low-order term. For example, if your guess is T(n) = n^2, then T(ceil(n/2)) ≤ T(n/2 + 1) = T(n/2) + n + 1. Really, though, one can do an entire PhD in algorithms without solving a single recurrence with the substitution method.